# Error 400 when trying to post Angular form information into ASP.NET Core API

Tags: asp.net, angular, api, crud

I'm a newbie in Angular. I tried to follow a tutorial from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCbaZixsP-s&t=3406s) and make a simple Angular app for doing CRUD operations. The angular version is 13. The API I'm using is ASP.NET Core 6. I wrote code for the API and tested it using Swagger. It was working fine. When I use Angular to post form data, it gives the following error:
[image]
API code is (relevant part):

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CardsController : Controller
{
private readonly CardsDbContext context;

        public CardsController(CardsDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
        //Get All Cards
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllCards()
        {
            var cards = await context.Cards.ToListAsync();
            return Ok(cards);
        }
        //Get single card
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{id:guid}")]
        [ActionName("GetCard")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCard([FromRoute]Guid id)
        {
            var card = await context.Cards.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
            if(card != null)
            {
                return Ok(card);
            }
            return NotFound("Card not found");
        }
        //Add single card
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddCard([FromBody] Card card)
        {
            card.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            await context.AddAsync(card);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetCard), new { Id = card.Id}, card); 
        }
}
```

The form used in Angular:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Card Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="cardName" [(ngModel)]="card.CardholderName">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Card Number:</label>
          <input type="number" name="cardNumber" [(ngModel)]="card.CardNumber">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-inline">
          <div>
            <label>CVC:</label>
            <input type="number" name="cardCVC" [(ngModel)]="card.CardCVC">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Expiry Month:</label>
            <input type="number" name="expiryMonth" [(ngModel)]="card.ExpiryMonth">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Expiry Date:</label>
            <input type="number" name="expiryCVC" [(ngModel)]="card.ExpiryYear">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

The service used in Angular:

```
export class CardsService {

  baseurl = "https://localhost:7195/api/cards";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //Get all cards
  GetAllCards(): Observable<Card[]>{
    return this.http.get<Card[]>(this.baseurl);
  }
  addCard(card: Card): Observable<Card>{
    card.id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
    return this.http.post<Card>(this.baseurl, card);
  }
}
```

The main component used in Angular (There is only one component):

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Cards';
  Cards: Card[] = [];
  card: Card = {
    id: '',
    CardNumber: '',
    CardCVC: '',
    CardholderName: '',
    ExpiryMonth: '',
    ExpiryYear: ''
  }

  constructor(private cardService: CardsService) {

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllCards();
  }

  getAllCards() {
    this.cardService.GetAllCards()
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          this.Cards = response
        }
      );
  }

  OnSubmit() {
    this.cardService.addCard(this.card).subscribe(
      response =>{
        console.log(response);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

I also used the following code in API to allow CORS:

```
builder.Services.AddCors((setup) =>
{
    setup.AddPolicy("Default", (options) =>
    {
        options.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin();
    });
});
app.UseCors("Default");
```

I searched many links but cannot find any good answer to solve my problem.

I tried to change angular service to something like this:

```
addCard(card: Card): Observable<Card>{
    card.id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
    return this.http.post<Card>(this.baseurl + "/addcard", card);
  }
```

But it gives an error of 405.

Update:
Swagger manual POST test:
[Swagger01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrnTS.png)
[Swagger02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ7mJ.png)

Comment: Provide the complete response data. Look like the request data was fail the validation.

Comment: The problem was solved by changing all input types into `text`. I don't know why!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Card Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="cardName" [(ngModel)]="card.CardholderName">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Card Number:</label>
          <input type="text" name="cardNumber" [(ngModel)]="card.CardNumber">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-group-inline">
          <div>
            <label>CVC:</label>
            <input type="text" name="cardCVC" [(ngModel)]="card.CardCVC">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Expiry Month:</label>
            <input type="text" name="expiryMonth" [(ngModel)]="card.ExpiryMonth">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Expiry Date:</label>
            <input type="text" name="expiryCVC" [(ngModel)]="card.ExpiryYear">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

I solved the problem by editing the card model in Angular.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).